# EXPLORER.EXE doesn't Autorun upon startup or CMD doesn't work

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, cmd.exe

Upon windows startup, I only see a CMD window where I have to run explorer.exe and from there everything goes "normal".

[image: My screen after log in]

I am pretty sure this has something to do with the AutoRun Registry which can be found at:

> "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"

As you can probably see in the image below, the value is set to nothing.

[image: My AutoRun Reg value]

When I first checked however, the value of AutoRun Reg was set to:

```
@mode 20,5 &
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq SoundMixer.exe" 2>NUL |
find /I /N "SoundMixer.exe">NUL && exit & if exist
"C:\Users\Leon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoundMixer\SoundMixer.exe" (
  start /MIN "" "C:\Users\Leon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoundMixer\SoundMixer.exe" &
  tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>NUL |
  find /I /N "explorer.exe">NUL && exit & explorer.exe & exit
)
else (
  tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>NUL |
  find /I /N "explorer.exe">NUL && exit & explorer.exe & exit
)
```

The problem with this registry value is that it seems to simply NOT let me open/run  Command prompt windows nor any Batch files.
I decided to empty the AutoRun registry value and created another problem where my PC startup begins with a terminal(CMD).

At this point I'm basically left with 2 choices:

1. Run explorer.exe ever time I log in to windows, but be able to use CMD/Batch files.

2. Not have to run explorer.exe upon start but live without using CMD/Batch files. (Not an option)

My question: 
how do I make explorer.exe autorun upon startup and also not mess the AutoRun registry in a way where I cant run any batch files and/or CMD's?

Answer (score 2):

[image: THE SHARED IMAGE DESCRIBES EVERYTHING]

Now what you ought to do:

1. if you are left with a terminal window open after the startup screen after you enter the password to your system to login.
2. if this is the case then type " explorer.exe" and press enter this will run the explorer and your system will return to normal appearance.
3. if you already have the system at normal state then no problem simply press "window key+ r" to open run command and type in "regedit" and press enter.

   Then observe from the image from the regedit address bar and navigate to the following folder using the address: "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" and then double click on key entry with name " Shell"
4. Change the value entry to from whatever it was in my case it was "%comspec% and change it to " explorer.exe" and press enter.
5. This will solve your issue to autorun explorer at startup and neither will the command prompt window appear on startup.